# parse timstamp in offset format

Tags: java, date

I want to parse a timestamp into a `OffsetDateTime` represented as following:

```
2019-08-02T30:17:48.128+0200
```

Note that there is no `:` between the hours and minutes in the offset notation, as expected by `OffsetDateTime`.

When feeding this to `OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-08-02T30:17:48.128+0200")`, I get a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`.

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code, please.

Comment: Did you remember to search before asking? What did you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `DateTimeFormatter` with `ZZZ` for the time zone offset.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ");
OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-08-02T10:17:48.128+0200", dtf);
```

Also, the hour in the example is not correct: 30 is not a valid value.